# need tutorials on Android Custom-List

Tags: android, list, custom-lists

last days I was browsing one of the apps in Android
and I found out an amazing list.

[image: Custom-List]

I Found that Custom `ListView` Interesting. 
When we click on the Text it shows me some `Activity` and when we click on the Arrow on Right it shows me a dialog.

I want to learn this. Can anybody go through some Tutorials where this Custom List is explained. Please Friends. guide me.. Thanks alot

Comment: I think you are looking for listview preferences. Why dont you google it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi Below Is Custom ListView Example

### First Create test.Java File below is code

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class test extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ArrayList<String> arrayString = new ArrayList<String>();
    test_adapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        arrayString.add("TextView1");
        arrayString.add("TextView2");
        arrayString.add("TextView3");
        arrayString.add("TextView4");
        arrayString.add("TextView5");
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.LIST);
        adapter = new test_adapter(this, arrayString);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

---

### Also Used below Class file test_adapter.java

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class test_adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public test_adapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> d) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView txt1;
        public Button btn1;
        public RelativeLayout rel1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
            holder.btn1 = (Button) vi.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
            holder.rel1 = (RelativeLayout) vi.findViewById(R.id.rel1);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        holder.txt1.setText(data.get(position));
        holder.rel1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast
                        .makeText(activity, "Click On TextView",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        holder.btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Click On Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });
        return vi;
    }

}
```

---

### Used below layout files main.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/LIST"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

### Used listview.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/rel1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txt1"
        android:text="Test Description"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btn1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ClickHere"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></Button>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

---

Used Above Code and you will get display toast message and you can changed as per you requirement.

Comment: Great Tut Nik. Well theres a lil Problem. When i click on the text It Blinks Once. Whats could be the possible problem and how can v resolve it?

Comment: Hi sHah. Please covered relative layout to textview with width= wrap content and in baseadpter class click relative layout instead of text view. then your problem is solved.